# Finding source of supposed spam emails on Linux

Tags: linux, email, spam-prevention, ubuntu-16.04

I rent a VPS from OVH. It runs Ubuntu 16.04.

My provider has emailed me, via its automatic reporting system, and claims that my server is sending spam. An example snippet from this report:

```
Our anti-spam protection layer has detected that your IP [my IP] is sending spam.

Destination IP: 152.163.0.100 - Message-ID: 20161230121402.19587.qmail@vpsXXXXX.ovh.net - Spam score: 300
```

They have blocked port 25 access at a network level. I can opt to unblock it, but I've done this once already and this is now the second report.

My problem is that I can't find any trace of these supposed emails.

Things I've tried:

- Used online tools and my own manual test to verify that the server is not an open relay: it is not
- Checked `/var/log/mail.log` and `/var/log/procmail.log` - nothing related to this
- Checked the various Apache logs for evidence of unusual web traffic
- Added mail logging to PHP5 & PHP7, tested it, waited several days - only my tests are recorded
- `postqueue -p` shows only my unsent tests
- searched the server for QMail: I don't even have an install. I use Postfix and Procmail.
- checked `last` for any suspicious activity
- upgraded everything I can as a 'hail mary'

All I can think of, false reporting aside, is that perhaps some other process outside of the mail infrastructure is compromised?

What more can I do?

Comment: wireshark on tcp port 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ipor's comment sent me down the right track - I used a long running instance of `tcpdump` to track activity, get a very specific timestamp, and then I managed to link that to an entry in `/var/log/auth.log` that told me one of the SSH accounts had been compromised.

Answer (score 0):

Try mailq, thats what we use on our email server to see emails being sent. Then use postcat to display the emails to narrow down the sender of the spam.

Comment: Try the command.s
postqueue -p
and
postcat -q messageid